# Problem with changing textarea's value using button (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a problem with my Note app. I'm trying to code an app that can save notes. I made a three modules - one for adding notes using the button, one for textarea validation and one for adding notes and marking them as added. The problem is that my button works fine from time to time. When it's broken this button work only on the previous element (I mean it that it should work for the current element and not for the next element like it's working from time to time.) Confirm.js's task is that it take `textarea.value` and save this to a `textarea.parentNode.textContent`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't know where is mistake.

Script.js

```
import {addNote} from './addNote.js';
import {textareaValidation} from './textareaValidation.js';
import {confirm} from './confirm.js';
(function(){
document.querySelector('button.btn-add-note').addEventListener('click', function() 
{addNote.createElement()}, false);

setInterval(function(){
    var btnConfirm = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn.confirm');
    var textArea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
        for(let i =0; i<textArea.length; i++){
        textArea[i].addEventListener('keypress', function(){textareaValidation.changeHeight(textArea[i])}, false);
        textArea[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(){textareaValidation.changeHeight(textArea[i])}, false);
        btnConfirm[i].addEventListener('click', function(){confirm.conf(textArea[i])}, false);
        }       

   },500)
   })();
```

Confirm.js

```
var confirm = (function(){
function conf(textarea){
    
    if(textarea.value.length>0){
    textarea.parentNode.textContent = textarea.value;
    }
}
var result = {
    conf: conf
};
return result;
})();
export {confirm};
```

Edit:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Note</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <span class="lato">Note app</span><button class='btn-add-note'>Add 
    note</button>
    </div>    
</div>
<script type='module' src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Addnote.js:

```
var addNote = (function(){
function createElement(){
    var note = document.createElement('div');
    note.classList.add('note');
    var noteHtml = "<span class='title lato'>Title: <input maxlength='18' 
 type='text'></input></span> <span class='content lato'>Content: <textarea 
 maxlength='255' rows='1'></textarea></span> <span class='block'>Character 
limit: 255/255</span> <button class='btn cancel'>Cancel</button><button 
class='btn confirm'>Confirm</button>";
    note.innerHTML = noteHtml;
    document.querySelector('div.container').appendChild(note);
}
var api={
    createElement: createElement
}

return api;
})();
export {addNote};
```

Comment: Post your HTML too

Comment: I added html and another module

Comment: Why would you add eventlisteners in an interval. You only need to do that once to the container

Comment: textarea.parentNode.textContent. will replace all content of the parentNode including the textarea. Can you please click edit, then `[<>]` and make a [mcve] without all those export statements?

Comment: This should replace all content but sometimes it doesn't work. I will try to add eventlistener only to container later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this

You will need to hook up some functions but this is a much simpler way

I wrapped the notes in a div (why all those spans???)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div.container');

function conf(textarea) {
  if (textarea.value.length > 0) {
    textarea.parentNode.textContent = textarea.value;
  }
}

function createElement() {
  var note = document.createElement('div');
  note.classList.add('note');
  var noteHtml = `<div><span class='title lato'>Title: <input maxlength='18' type='text'></input></span> 
<span class='content lato'>Content: <textarea maxlength='255' rows='1'></textarea></span> 
<span class='block'>Character limit: 255/255</span> 
<button class='btn cancel'>Cancel</button>
<button class='btn confirm'>Confirm</button></div>`;
  note.innerHTML = noteHtml;
  container.appendChild(note);
}

container.addEventListener("input",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="TEXTAREA") {
    textareaValidation.changeHeight(tgt)
  }
})  
container.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("confirm")) {
    conf(tgt.closest("div").querySelector("textarea"))
  }
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("btn-add-note")) {
    createElement()
  }
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("cancel")) {
    tgt.closest("div").remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <span class="lato">Note app</span> <button class='btn-add-note'>Add note</button>
  </div>
</div>
```